# Get url to web api controller method in the Razor Pages app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-5.0

I have the index.cshtml under the /Pages folder. And the  web api controller in the same folder:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController: ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> GetValue(){
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

Now I'm expected that this code should work (as it works in Asp Core 2):

```
var apiUri = Url.Action(action: "GetValue", controller: "Values");
var apiUri2 = Url.ActionLink(action: "GetValue", controller: "Values");
```

But it doesn't work (return nulls)! As well as all other options I have tried :

```
 var apiUri3 = Url.Action(action: "GetValue", controller: "ValuesController");
```

How to force `Url.Action` work for web api controller in CORE 3 (4 and 5)?

Here is the `IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider.ActionDescriptors.Items` information : [image]

Project structure (actually core web app):

[image]

Command window results:

```
>? Url.Action(action: "GetValue", controller: "Values");
null
>? Url.Action(action: "GetValue", controller: "ValuesController");
null
>? Url.Action(action: "Value", controller: "ValuesController");
null
>? Url.Action(action: "Value", controller: "Values");
null
>
```

For those who minus as "obvious" (I guess), test youself:

1. [ApiController] commented out (controller is no marked as ApiController); [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")] added; no endpoints.* modifications  - is the controller "routable"? (answer "no")
2. still not [ApiController] but now we add endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "api/[controller]/[action]"); - is the controller "routable"? (answer "yes")
3. now we additionaly to (2) comment out [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]  - is the controller "routable"? (answer "no")
4. now return [Route("api/[area]/[controller]/[action]")] but also add [ApiController] and add [Area("myarea")]  is the controller "routable"? (answer "no")

Comment: What do you need it for . Could you please post the whole code instead of one line?

Comment: I want to know how to get the URI of the web api method dinamically. There is no body actually it is a sample empty method.

Comment: What is wrong with var apiPostMessageUri="/ChatApi/PostMessage" ?

Comment: This  depends on routing configuration. I prepare depend directly on controller and method names, less abstraction leaks. Now, my question what wrong is with Url.Action ?

Comment: Sorry , never heard about anything like this.

Comment: where is your `ChatApiController`? is it loaded dynamically? The `Url.Action` should work for all ***known controllers*** (meaning it can detect that the controller and action do exist). In case the controller is not known at runtime, it will return null. Still not sure how could this be an issue, because if your controller is loaded at runtime, at the time you use `Url.Action`, it should be aware of as well.

Comment: @KingKing it is located in the Pages folder. I do not do anything in code to load it or to route to the it.

Comment: You can try another project to see that ***it should work***. The only reason I know for it to return `null` is the controller or action is not existing. But in your question, they look matching with your defined endpoint.

Comment: @KingKing it is done in the new core web app project. With the same result the same coding was done under new web api empty controller ValuesController added under the "Pages" folder and new method added to it. then the  Url.Action is added into the `index.cshtml`. But it is not so clear for me that **it should work** . E.g. the default routing could be configured that web api controller 'method name not become the part of uri' and this misslead the `Url.Action`...

Comment: @RomanPokrovskij because I've tried it myself, it should work. There must be something wrong on your side.

Comment: Why would a *MVC Specific Features (UrlHelper, in the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing namespace)* want to interact with a non-mvc controller (specifically ControllerBase that doesn't include View related methods)?

Comment: @ErikPhilips This have sense, but still it was ok in Core and Core 2. How to get URL of non-mvc controller action?

Comment: Why would you want to?  Url.Action is for creating URLs for *navigation*.  Nobody navigates to an API method.

Comment: @ErikPhilips This is still controller and action - the same form of the code organization. Why the consistency should be ruined? I use it for long time - I just do not want to think about concreate routing in final code (all those prefixes and areas). I get uri's dinamically and pass them to my javascipt code.

Comment: @ErikPhilips BTW the [ApiController]  and "non-MVC" ControllerBase belongs to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc. Even in Core 3. You think, this the wrong way to povide web api ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it does not work its because the routing for ApiController works different.

In your example:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController: ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> GetValue(){
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

Assuming that this in localhost

Really means the route is "http://localhost/api/Values"

if you want for example "http://localhost/api/Values/GetValue" you need to do:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController: ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("GetValue")]//notice the extra piece of route we added here
    public IEnumerable<string> GetValue()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    [HttpGet("GetAnotherValue")]//notice the extra piece of route we added here
    public IEnumerable<string> GetValue()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

As for using Url.Action you might get away with using something like:

```
///api/Values/GetValue"
var apiUri1 = Url.Action(action: "GetValue", controller: "Values");

///api/Values/GetAnotherValue"
var apiUri2 = Url.Action(action: "GetAnotherValue", controller: "Values");
```

Finally you need to make sure you mapped the api controller routes

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers(); // Map attribute-routed API controllers
    //endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute(); // Map conventional MVC controllers using the default route
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();//map razor pages
});
```

Finally your "ApiController" controllers do not need to be in the "Pages" folder.
Api controllers route by Attributes not by "folder location". I suggest you put them inside a folder called Controllers in the root of your project.

The other answer in this post seems to "work" but as soon as you add another action to the the API controller you will realize it produces the wrong urls on the Url.Action calls because in ApiControllers the routing does not happen by "Method Name"

Comment: this means that you put your controllers ***in an area***. There is no special convention to treat the prefix part in your route pattern (`api`) as an implicit area.

Comment: You have to put the "api" portion somewhere. Also imagine that "api" could be anything else like "serverEnpoint" or anything else.

Comment: I'm sure that you have an area named `api` (proved by the way you use `Url.Action` with a provided value for `area` as `"api"`. On my side, there is no such area, I declared the api controller normally (just a basic example), and it just works (`Url.Action` does not require any `area` to be provided). I've never read something like you must provide that `area` argument if you don't actually have such an area. The Web API does not have such an implicit area.

Comment: I dont have an "area" in my project... ApiController controllers do not use folder location routing they use attribute based routing.  The "area" here is just a "hack" to force the Url.Action to inject the string "api" into tje url like this "{area}/{controller}/{action}"

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro Attribute routing "enables" correct routing and Url.Action. `endpoints.MapControllers()` even do not required if attribute routing used. Thank you. Can you explain why "traditional" pattern routing `endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller}/{action}");` doesn't work ? From the name `MapControllerRoute` we can expect that this should work, but...

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro it is interesting that `endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller}/{action}");` alone enables Url.Action as it would be endpoints.MapControllers() called inside it. The Url.Action  returns "/api/Values" without action inspite of the `{action}` was specified.

Comment: @KingKing have you an answer on the q why `endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller}/{action}");` doesn't work properly ({action} for web api controller is not included into the routing path)... It looks like attribute routing can't be skipped.

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro additional quesiton moved to the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67463168/can-i-replace-the-attribute-routing-with-traditional-route-patterns-for-the-web

Comment: So the final consideration is that the simplest way is to modify `[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]` attribute (by adding [action]) and put the  `endpoints.MapControllers();` to the Startup (only Route is not enough). Then routing by `HttpGet|HttpPost` routing pattern is not required in general case.