# Can I replace the attribute routing with traditional route patterns for the web api controllers?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, asp.net-core-5.0

I have web api ValuesController (marked with `[ApiController]`) and the method [HttpPost] GetValue inside.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> GetValue()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

I have modifeid e Startup.cs

```
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller}/{action}"); // added
        });
```

Now I expect that route to the method should  be `/api/Values/GetValue` when it is the `/api/Values` - means the `{action}` is ignored?

Can the default routing be configured to include {action} to the uri? Now I'm forcing to attribute actions with the `[HttpGet(nameof(GetValue))]` what look verbose.

I understand that controller marked with ApiController is specific thing, but should it "react" to the MapControllerRoute ? I can't find it in the documentation.

Comment: In c# you can have in a class have the same method with different parameter lists like : MyMethod(int) or MyMethod(string).  So the Action is the parameter list in a HTTP GET.  So in some cases a Controler in a client may get different response with the same route.  The response would depend on the parameters in the request. You have to remember a Controller can be used in either a client or server to parse the receive data in a body of a message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attribute route always has a higher priority  then a default route. So if you want to have /api/Values/GetValue by default you can change controller attribute

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
```

Or if you want to use default route of startup,  you have to remove attribute routing from the controller and fix your default route:

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "api/{controller}/{action}");
```

Comment: Thank you. If I remove class `[Route]` attribute and `[HttpGet]`|`[HttpPost]` route paremeter then I get `System.InvalidOperationException : 'WebApplication2.Pages.ValuesController.GetValue (WebApplication3)' does not have an attribute route. Action methods on controllers annotated with ApiControllerAttribute must be attribute routed.`

So it seems the answer is **no**: there are no way to use `endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "api/{controller}/{action}"); ` to set a default web api controller name with action...

Comment: `[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]` sufficient workaround

Comment: P.S. To use `[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]`  the Startup modification `endpoints.MapControllers()`  required what is not so obvious. Or to call `endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "api/{controller}/{action}");` possibly because there is call endpoints.MapControllers() inside it, what is even less obvious.